# CreateJS Tick function not updating from external values.

Tags: createjs

I think this might be quite basic, I'm still learning CreateJS. I won't include all the code as its a large program but basically.

Outside of my tick function I have this code:

```
var hitOrMiss = 'Mada';        

function hit()
    {
    hitOrMiss = 'Hit';
    //alert(hitOrMiss);
    }
function miss()
    {
    hitOrMiss = 'Miss';
    //alert(hitOrMiss);
    }
```

When I click a button and call these they are testing ok (alerting out the values).

Inside my tick() function the values are not being picked up.

```
if(hitOrMiss = 'Mada')
{
    var basic = 'basic';
}
else if(hitOrMiss = 'Hit')
{
    if(gamePrincessBmpAnimation.x < 1000)
    {
    gamePrincessBmpAnimation.x += gamePrincessBmpAnimation.vX;
    var basic = 'Not basic';
    }
}
else if(hitOrMiss = 'Miss')
{
    if(gamePrincessBmpAnimation.x > 60)
    {
    gamePrincessBmpAnimation.x -+ gamePrincessBmpAnimation.vX;
    var basic = 'Miss Not basic';
    }
}
```

Do I need to specify a listener, if so how should it be set up?

I have already triggered the below, Does something similar need to be added to the tick function?

```
createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
gameStage.update();
```

The other if statements within the tick function are all firing, an example of which:

```
if (bmpAnimation.x >= screen_width - 16) {
    // We've reached right side of our screen
    // We need to walk left to go back to our initial position
    bmpAnimation.direction = -90;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Fixed this one, wasn't a createJS issue, was a silly Javascript issue, the code here:  else if(hitOrMiss = 'Hit') should have been else if(hitOrMiss == 'Hit')  etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this one, wasn't a createJS issue, was a silly Javascript issue, the code here:  else if(hitOrMiss = 'Hit') should have been else if(hitOrMiss == 'Hit')  etc.